# Macdeployqt could not find any external Qt frameworks to deploy

Tags: c++, qt, deployment, qml, macdeployqt

I made a simple animation in Qt/Qml. 
I can build the release version fine, with no errors. It also runs correctly. As the project is finished, I tried to deploy it with `macdeployqt` like this :

```
./Qt/5.6/clang_64/bin/macdeployqt /Users/etcg/Documents/qt/build-Windmill-Animation-Executer-Desktop_Qt_5_6_0_clang_64bit-Release/Windmill-Animation-Executer.app
```

but it gives me the following errors:

```
WARNING:
WARNING: Could not find any external Qt frameworks to deploy in "/Users/etcg/Documents/qt/build-Windmill-Animation-Executer-Desktop_Qt_5_6_0_clang_64bit-Release/Windmill-Animation-Executer.app"
WARNING: Perhaps macdeployqt was already used on "/Users/etcg/Documents/qt/build-Windmill-Animation-Executer-Desktop_Qt_5_6_0_clang_64bit-Release/Windmill-Animation-Executer.app" ?
WARNING: If so, you will need to rebuild "/Users/etcg/Documents/qt/build-Windmill-Animation-Executer-Desktop_Qt_5_6_0_clang_64bit-Release/Windmill-Animation-Executer.app" before trying again.
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is there something wrong with my Qt installation? How do I fix this problem?

**Note**: This is my first time using `macdeployqt`.

---

**Edit :**

In order to check the libraires dependencies, I ran `otool -L`.

The result of `otool -L /Users/etcg/Documents/qt/build-Windmill-Animation-Executer-Desktop_Qt_5_6_0_clang_64bit-Release/Windmill-Animation-Executer.app/Contents/MacOS/Windmill-Animation-Executer` is this :

```
/Users/etcg/Documents/qt/build-Windmill-Animation-Executer-Desktop_Qt_5_6_0_clang_64bit-Release/Windmill-Animation-Executer.app/Contents/MacOS/Windmill-Animation-Executer:
    @rpath/QtQuick.framework/Versions/5/QtQuick (compatibility version 5.6.0, current version 5.6.0)
    @rpath/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets (compatibility version 5.6.0, current version 5.6.0)
    @rpath/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui (compatibility version 5.6.0, current version 5.6.0)
    @rpath/QtQml.framework/Versions/5/QtQml (compatibility version 5.6.0, current version 5.6.0)
    @rpath/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/5/QtNetwork (compatibility version 5.6.0, current version 5.6.0)
    @rpath/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore (compatibility version 5.6.0, current version 5.6.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Versions/A/AGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.1.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1226.10.1)
```

Comment: Check the binary file in the bundle `Windmill-Animation-Executer.app`. Does it have the same name?

Comment: @IAmInPLS Yes, it has the same name

Comment: Can you type in your command line `otool -L Windmill-...app/Contents/MacOS/Windmill..` and post the result in your question?

Comment: @IAmInPLS Alright, please give me a minute.

Comment: @IAmInPLS Ok, I added it.

Comment: Oh wait, you don't have any error in fact! Only warnings, right?

Comment: @IAmInPLS Yes, but then when I try to run the actual app itself with `open -a ....app`, I get the following: `LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed for the application /Users/etcg/Documents/qt/build-Windmill-Animation-Executer-Desktop_Qt_5_6_0_clang_64bit-Release/Windmill-Animation-Executer.app with error -10810.` (after using macdeployqt)

Comment: @IAmInPLS Also, when running the executable itself, I get the following output: `dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/QtQuick.framework/Versions/5/QtQuick
  Referenced from: /Users/etcg/Documents/qt/build-Windmill-Animation-Executer-Desktop_Qt_5_6_0_clang_64bit-Release/Windmill-Animation-Executer.app/Contents/MacOS/Windmill-Animation-Executer
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5`

Comment: Try something like this `install_name_tool -change @rpath/QtQuick.framework/Versions/5/QtQuick @executable_path/../../../../../QtQuick.framework/Versions/5/QtQuick /Users/etcg/Documents/qt/build-Windmill-Animation-Executer-Desktop_Qt_5_6_0_clan‌​g_64bit-Release/Windmill-Animation-Executer.app/Contents/MacOS/Windmill-Animation‌​-Executer` (not sure about everything but basically I think the `rpath` is wrongly recognized. So you have to replace the QtQuick framework path yourself)

Comment: @IAmInPLS Sorry, what does the `/../../../../..` represent?

Comment: The path from the executable to `QtQuick.framework`. It might not be the same for you, that's why I said I was not sure

Comment: @IAmInPLS Oh, thought it meant I had to include something else. Forgot that `/../` brings you back a directory. I'll test out that command and report back now.

Comment: @IAmInPLS Ok, command provided no output, but now the app still won't open. What should I do now? By the way, thanks for all of your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114246/discussion-between-iaminpls-and-flare-cat).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following our discussion in the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114246/discussion-between-iaminpls-and-flare-cat), it seems that you managed to get it working, so that's great! As I suspected, your [`@rpath`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/100-Articles/RunpathDependentLibraries.html) was misleading (Qt's fault I guess). So the way to fix it is to link the Qt libraries using `@executable_path` instead of `@rpath` (you can go [here](https://wincent.com/wiki/@executable_path,_@load_path_and_@rpath) to know the difference).

To do that, follow these steps :

1/ Run the executable **itself** : you will get an error message like this :

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Qt*.framework/Versions/5/Qt*
>
> Referenced from:
> your_executable_name
>
> Reason: image not found Trace/BPT trap: 5

where `*` is the name of the Qt library. You are told that the library is not well referenced so **you have to change the path where it is referenced from**.

2/ To do that, use the command `install_name_tool` like that :

```
install_name_tool -change @rpath/Qt*.framework/Versions/5/Qt* @executable_path/your/path/to/the/framework/Qt*.framework/Versions/5/Qt* /your/path/to/your/executable
```

Now, you have changed the path (you can check that with `otool -L`).

3/ If the change is correct, either you have no problem anymore, or you have to do this for other Qt libs. Indeed, `*` can be `Quick`, but it can also be `Gui`, `Network`, etc (Qt libs in fact). So go back to step 1!

Once you're done with all the libs, your application starts as you desired.

Comment: Ok, thanks for making an official answer. Now my application says it can't find the Cocoa framework on the target computer. Is this a simple fix, or should I post another question?

Comment: I think you can ask a new question!